# Should i use one UDP receiver for multiple connection (JAVA)

Tags: java

I'm creating multiplayer server - client using UDP method. In UDP, there is only one way to receive every packet which is socket.receive(packet). If there are many clients send data at the same time, how can one socket.receive(packet) can handle it all and fast? Thankyou

Comment: Allow me to suggest you to kindly provide examples of what you have tried so far. A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: The question and answer to this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8973427/java-udp-socket-data-are-left-over-at-the-server-side) may be useful to you